# Removing User from a specific group in a specific OU

Tags: powershell, get-aduser

Hello guys I have this

```
function Invoke-AdDesktopGGroup {
 [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
 param($ADGroup)

 #$OUPath = "OU=SCPA,DC=souche,DC=ban"
 $user = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=SCPA,DC=soucy,DC=lan" -Filter * -Properties MemberOf
 $user | foreach {
 if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($_.Name, 'Remove Group')) {
 $_ | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_ -Confirm $false
 }
 }
}
```

And what i seek is to remove Every user in the SCPA OU who have the group named Desktop Global
The command I write for this is as following
Invoke-AdDesktopGGroup -ADGroup 'Desktop Global' -Whatif

Can you guys help me, I'm kinda stuck.

Answer (score 0):

So, something like this?

```
function Invoke-AdDesktopGroup {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$ADGroup
    )
    Begin {

         
         $ADGroup_Splat = @{
             SearchBase = 'OU=SCPA,DC=soucy,DC=lan'
             Filter     = '*'
             Properties = 'MemberOf'
         }
         $ADUsers = Get-ADUser @ADGroup_Splat
     

    }
    Process{
        
        # Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Members $ADUsers -Confirm:$false # I believe this is all you would need instead of a foreach loop
        foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($User.Name, 'Remove Group')) {

                Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Members $User.Name -Confirm:$false

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I don't have any user I can test this on, but it should work. Take note of the inline-comment; I believe it can take an array of users after looking at the syntax for `Remove-ADGroupMember`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I was able to get it to work like this

```
function Invoke-AdDesktopGroup {
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    Param($ADGroup)
    Begin {

         
         $ADGroup_Splat = @{
             SearchBase = 'OU=SCPA,DC=soucy,DC=lan'
             Filter     = '*'
             Properties = 'MemberOf'
         }
         $ADUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup
     

    }
    Process{
        
       foreach ($User in $ADUsers) {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($User.Name, 'Remove Group')) {

                Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $ADGroup -Members $User.Name -Confirm:$false

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Seems like the parameter you gave me didn't work. Powershell couldn't convert the string parameter into Active Directory parameter. But neither the less, I was able to get it to work by your input. Thanks a lot!